# creating html helper equavalent to nopcomerce @T() helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, html-helper, nopcommerce

I was working on NopCommerce, and it has an HTML helper `@T("")` that takes a string key and fetches its value from the database.

I want to implement this in my project. I googled a lot but didn't find any help on how they created a helper method like this.

Can somebody help me creating similar helper like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell razor to use your own `WebViewPage`.  You declare this inside the `web.config` file under `Views` folder.  Your custom `WebViewPage` must be specified in the `pageBaseType` attribute of the `pages` element.  All the cshtml implementations will inherit your custom `WebViewPage` and you can access the pulic or protected properties and method of your custom `WebViewPage`.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, 
                 Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="Custom.MyCustomWebViewPage">
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check in `Nop.Web.Framework`?

`T` Is custom HTML helper of nopcoomerce, you can find it's implementation at
`Nop.Web.Framework > ViewEngines > Razor > WebViewPage`

It's just call `GetResource` service to get resources string.

```
    public Localizer T
    {
        get
        {
            if (_localizer == null)
            {
                //null localizer
                //_localizer = (format, args) => new LocalizedString((args == null || args.Length == 0) ? format : string.Format(format, args));

                //default localizer
                _localizer = (format, args) =>
                                 {
                                     var resFormat = _localizationService.GetResource(format);
                                     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resFormat))
                                     {
                                         return new LocalizedString(format);
                                     }
                                     return
                                         new LocalizedString((args == null || args.Length == 0)
                                                                 ? resFormat
                                                                 : string.Format(resFormat, args));
                                 };
            }
            return _localizer;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did the same but I am unable to call it in .cshtml page

Comment: I have already tried all above things. If you could help me accessing it in .cshtml page that would be very helpful.